# My Firefox on mac crashes and I cannot open it anymore

Tags: firefox

My Firefox on mac crashes and I cannot open it anymore (Leopard)

I was wondering how to remove extensions and preferences. I've deleted

- Mozilla folder in my Library
- Mozilla folder in hard disk library
- Downloaded and replaced Firefox application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mac the extensions and prefs are at `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile>/`
If you remove or move that folder, firefox should start with the default profile.